# Creating shortcut to Oracle SQL Developer on desktop

Tags: 16.04

To start Oracle SQL Developer I have to write 
cd /opt/sqldeveloper/
./sqldeveloper.sh

I tried to make a shortcut to the sqldeveloper.sh file on my desktop, but when I run the shortcut I only see the script in gedit. It doesnt run it.

How can I make the script run when I click my desktop shortcut?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu.SE! Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic). - did you set the `executable` flag using 'chamod'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, my guess is that it's not set as an executable. Check it's permissions.

From the command line you can run the following to add execute permissions to the file:

```
chmod +x sqldeveloper.sh
```

Another method I'd recommend is creating a shortcut would be the following:

```
cd /usr/share/applications
sudo gedit ./sqldeveloper.desktop
```

This will open an empty file in Gedit.

In the file, add the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=SQL Developer
Comment=Oracle SQL Developer
GenericName=SQL Developer for Linux
Exec=/opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh
Type=Application
Categories=Developer;
Icon=/opt/sqldeveloper/icon.png
```

Save the file.

Now if you use the Search for SQL Developer in your app menu, you'll find SQL Developer and you can run it from there.

Now you can either add that as a favorite of yours or you can drag and drop it to your desktop.

To confirm, I just did this process myself while writing this up.

You can also reference this post for other ways to do what you're looking to do.

[How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop)

Comment: Does not seem to work for me, It does add it in the app menu though but does not launch the application. I have even validated .desktop file with *desktop-file-validate* tool. Using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Answer (score 1):

Create a desktop shortcut:

1. Create shortcut file

```
sudo vim /usr/share/applications/sqldeveloper.desktop
```

2. Enter the shortcut details:

```
    [Desktop Entry]
    Name=SQL Developer
    Comment=Oracle SQL Developer
    GenericName=SQL Developer
    Exec=/path/to/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh &
    Type=Application
    Categories=Developer;
    Icon=/path/to/sqldeveloper/icon.png
```

3. Validate permissions. Ensure sqldeveloper.sh is executable

```
    chmod +x sqldeveloper.sh
```